# Does "an example to other team members" refer to members of the same team or of different teams?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, sentence-usage

What's the exact meaning of the sentence **'This is an example to other team members'**?

This is an example to the members of other team or This is an example to other members of the same team?

Can anyone explain a little bit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, it means "other members of the same team".

If it was designed to mean "members of the *other* team", it would need to read:

> This is an example to *the* other *team's* members.

Or, if there are several "other teams":

> This is an example to *the* other *teams'* members.

Answer (score 1):

> This is an example to other team members

means this is an example to other members of the same team,**team members** means the members of a team

If it meant the members of other teams, it would have to use *teams' members* like

> This is an example to the other teams' members